# Create a dictionary inside of FOR loop and the Create a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I have a list of lists

```
tours = [[0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [1, 13], [2, 0], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 10],
[6, 7], [7, 1], [8, 2], [9, 3], [10, 11], [11, 14], [12, 0], [13, 12], [14, 0]]
```

I also have a dataframe `df`:

```
    Node       X      Y  Demand  Profit
1      2  5.7735   0.00    40.0    16.0
2      3  2.8867   5.00    40.0    16.0
3      4 -2.8868   5.00    40.0    16.0
4      5 -5.7735   0.00    40.0    16.0
5      6 -2.8867  -5.00    40.0    16.0
6      7  2.8868  -5.00    40.0    16.0
7      8  8.6603   5.00    40.0    24.0
8      9  0.0000  10.00    40.0    24.0
9     10 -8.6603   5.00    40.0    24.0
10    11 -8.6603  -5.00    40.0    24.0
11    12  0.0000 -10.00    40.0    24.0
12    13  8.6603  -5.00    40.0    24.0
13    14  5.3405   0.75    10.0    10.0
14    15  3.3198   4.25    10.0    10.0
15    16  6.4952  -1.25    10.0    11.0
```

In the list of lists "tour" the first element of a list member defines the element in column `X` and the second element of the list member defines the element in column `Y`.
For example `[0,4]` points to `X=5.7735`, `Y= -5.00`.

I need to create a new dataframe `coord` with two columns `X` and `Y` where each row represents an `X`,`Y` pair defined by an element in `tours`.

My plan is to create a dictionary and then create a new dataframe but I am struggling with getting column names to a new dataframe or having a duplicated index column and splitting the elements of the list.

Here is my code

```
d = {}

for t,tour in enumerate(tours):

    xi = tour[0]
    yi = tour[1]
    key = t
    d[key] = df["X"].iloc[xi], df["Y"].iloc[yi]

print(d)
coord = pd.DataFrame(d.items(),columns=['X', 'Y'])
print(coord)
```

Output:

```
{0: (5.7735, -5.0), 1: (5.7735, -5.0), 2: (5.7735, 5.0), 3: (2.8867, 4.25), 4: (-2.8868, 0.0), 5: (-5.7735, 5.0), 6: (-2.8867, -5.0), 7: (2.8868, -10.0), 8: (8.6603, 10.0), 9: (0.0, 5.0), 10: (-8.6603, 5.0), 11: (-8.6603, 0.0), 12: (0.0, -5.0), 13: (8.6603, -1.25), 14: (5.3405, 0.0), 15: (3.3198, 0.75), 16: (6.4952, 0.0)}
     X                Y
0    0   (5.7735, -5.0)
1    1   (5.7735, -5.0)
2    2    (5.7735, 5.0)
3    3   (2.8867, 4.25)
4    4   (-2.8868, 0.0)
5    5   (-5.7735, 5.0)
6    6  (-2.8867, -5.0)
7    7  (2.8868, -10.0)
8    8   (8.6603, 10.0)
9    9       (0.0, 5.0)
10  10   (-8.6603, 5.0)
11  11   (-8.6603, 0.0)
12  12      (0.0, -5.0)
13  13  (8.6603, -1.25)
14  14    (5.3405, 0.0)
15  15   (3.3198, 0.75)
16  16    (6.4952, 0.0)
```

I greatly appreciate your help!

My ultimate goal is to plot a full rout using `X` and `Y` as coordinates. Any advise will be greatly appreciated.

PS.
Here is what I came up with. It works but I will appreciate any improvements:

```
d = {}
    for t,tour in enumerate(tours):

        xi = tour[0]
        yi = tour[1]
    
        key = t
        d[key] = df["X"].iloc[xi], df["Y"].iloc[yi]

    coord = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns= ['X','Y'])
```

OUTPUT:

```
    X      Y
0   5.7735  -5.00
1   5.7735  -5.00
2   5.7735   5.00
3   2.8867   4.25
4  -2.8868   0.00
5  -5.7735   5.00
6  -2.8867  -5.00
7   2.8868 -10.00
8   8.6603  10.00
9   0.0000   5.00
10 -8.6603   5.00
11 -8.6603   0.00
12  0.0000  -5.00
13  8.6603  -1.25
14  5.3405   0.00
15  3.3198   0.75
16  6.4952   0.00
```

Is there an easier way that LoL to dict to dataframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to write the for loop so you do not get the tuple values as the Y column in the coord Dataframe:

```
coord_data = []
for pair in tours:
    xidx, yidx = pair
    x, y = df.loc[xidx, 'X'], df.loc[yidx, 'Y']
    coord_data.append([x, y])

# Convert the list to a DataFrame
coord = pd.DataFrame(coord_data, columns=['X', 'Y'])
```

Comment: it gives and error in: x, y = df.loc[xidx, 'X'], df.loc[yidx, 'Y'] - KeyError 0. I think should be something like: df["X"].iloc[xidx] You may want to check

Comment: *"KeyError 0"* Probably the index of df starts at 1 not 0. Try to add 1 to xidx and yidx

Comment: It does not work. The index starts with 0. I had the same issue at a different place and it turned out that my indexing code was wrong

Comment: Try this script: https://pastebin.com/AGy6x6Zu. It works for me.

Comment: I got that. I think it is the most elegant answer. Thank you EVERYONE!

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```py
tours = np.array(tours)
arr = df[["X", "Y"]].to_numpy()
out = pd.DataFrame({"X": arr[tours[:, 0], 0], "Y": arr[tours[:, 1], 1]})

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
         X      Y
0   5.7735  -5.00
1   5.7735  -5.00
2   5.7735   5.00
3   2.8867   4.25
4  -2.8868   0.00
5  -5.7735   5.00
6  -2.8867  -5.00
7   2.8868 -10.00
8   8.6603  10.00
9   0.0000   5.00
10 -8.6603   5.00
11 -8.6603   0.00
12  0.0000  -5.00
13  8.6603  -1.25
14  5.3405   0.00
15  3.3198   0.75
16  6.4952   0.00
```